# Github action works on push but not scheduled

Tags: github-actions

I am running the example of javascript github actions and it works just fine when I have

> on: [push]

but not when I have

```
on:
  schedule:
    - cron:  '*/5 * * * *'
```

I expect the github action to run every 5 minutes but it doesn't seem to run at all.

Here is the rest of my code for reference

*.github/worflows/main.yml*

```
on:
  schedule:
    - cron:  '*/5 * * * *'

jobs:
  hello_world_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: A job to say hello
    steps:
    - name: Hello world action step
      id: hello
      uses: StephenVNelson/website/@3-experiment-with-actions
      with:
        who-to-greet: 'Mona the Octocat'
    # Use the output from the `hello` step
    - name: Get the output time
      run: echo "The time was ${{ steps.hello.outputs.time }}"
```

*./action.yml*

```
name: 'Hello World'
description: 'Greet someone and record the time'
inputs:
  who-to-greet:  # id of input
    description: 'Who to greet'
    required: true
    default: 'World'
outputs:
  time: # id of output
    description: 'The time we greeted you'
runs:
  using: 'node12'
  main: './github-actions/main.js'
```

*./github-actions/main.js*

```
const core = require('@actions/core');
const github = require('@actions/github');

try {
  // `who-to-greet` input defined in action metadata file
  const nameToGreet = core.getInput('who-to-greet');
  console.log(`Hello ${nameToGreet}!`);
  const time = (new Date()).toTimeString();
  core.setOutput("time", time);
  // Get the JSON webhook payload for the event that triggered the workflow
  const payload = JSON.stringify(github.context.payload, undefined, 2)
  console.log(`The event payload: ${payload}`);
} catch (error) {
  core.setFailed(error.message);
}
```

Comment: Does the workflow output/throw any errors? Is the tag you've specified valid?

Comment: Also, could you try moving the workflow to the default branch? As mentioned in the documentation of event types (specifically the [`schedule` event](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#scheduled-events-schedule)), _"Scheduled workflows run on the latest commit on the default or base branch."_

Comment: @Edric I am so confused. I finally got the scheduled event to start running and here is exactly what I did.
1) I added the action to the main branch like you said. Still nothing happened. 
2) On a whim I decided to create another workflow straight from the github site for this same repository that also runs on a schedule.

I have no idea why but that seemed to unplug whatever problem was there because all of a sudden my other scheduled workflows started running.

Comment: Same thing for me, it only started working after I created another workflow that runs on a schedule. I was working on a fork. After I created it, it ran, and the other one also started running on its schedule.

Comment: It seems to be just a delay. After I pushing the workflow, it did not start to schedule for the first few hours. But after that, without any other interactions, the schedule works well except that it is several times per hour instead of exactly once per 5 minutes as is specified in the config.

Comment: For me there was a few minutes delay from the schedule time set in the script before it actually run, so I started to panic and found this thread. The action did run while I was reading.

Comment: @PrzemysławWrzesiński I am also getting these delayed by a few minutes (25 in my case) runs. There's nothing mentioned on Github's docs. A warning from their part would be much appreciated.

Comment: I found this [issue](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/2381), which implies that jobs are added to a queue, and can stay in that queue for a long time before actually being executed. The event (e.g. push, PR, or cron schedule) only adds the job to the queue, it doesn't actually start the job itself, which explains the delay for cron scheduling to actual start and completion of the job. So, if your workflow run is sensitive to specific times, maybe don't rely on GitHub Actions.

Comment: @jidicula That issue involves only macOS runners.

In any case, it is for sure true that there is a queuing done in the back scenes from their end. But it's definetly not reasonable for those jobs to stay in that queue for half an hour... 

I have contacted their support. They told me it's something they are aware about, and are looking into a fix.

Comment: Seems to be a ongoing issue with crons and GitHub Actions [here](https://github.community/t/cron-job-actions-not-scheduling-properly/145662) and [here](https://github.community/t/scheduled-jobs-are-not-running-on-time/121271) and [here](https://upptime.js.org/blog/2021/01/22/github-actions-schedule-not-working/)

Answer (score 7):

(Editor's note: For the future readers, do read the comment of this answer for an update of the frequency.)

You won't be able to schedule it for every 5 minutes as the "shortest interval you can run scheduled workflows is once every 15 minutes":

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#schedule

Change it to '*/15 * * * *' and you'll be fine.

Comment: That link now states that the most frequent schedule is 5 minutes - "The shortest interval you can run scheduled workflows is once every 5 minutes."

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the GitHub documentation about [Scheduled events](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#scheduled-events)

> The schedule event can be delayed during periods of high loads of GitHub Actions workflow runs. High load times include the start of every hour. To decrease the chance of delay, schedule your workflow to run at a different time of the hour.

Read further : [No assurance on scheduled jobs?](https://github.community/t/no-assurance-on-scheduled-jobs/133753)

Answer (score 0):

I recommends to use some trigger apps like IFTTT, Zappier or even AWS Lamda functions etc to handle this case.

Github actions docs says that the cron job scheduled may not work as expected and its a known issue.

If you want to do some critical tasks on time like release the code everyday 8:30 AM , merge the master to other branches on midnight etc can be handled using the apps mentioned above.